# CSS @media print margins

Tags: html, css, printing

I am trying to print a div on a single page. The div contains a dynamic table which can have more columns depending on what's selected. The number or rows is static.

Printing a page with lots of columns works fine but if only a few it creates a second page.

If I remove:

```
left: 0;
```

It will print on a single page for a page with a few columns but if there are then lots of them it cuts the bottom few rows.

How can I get this to show on a single page no matter the content on the page.

When printing I currently have:

```
@media print {
  body * {
      visibility: hidden;
  }

  #section-to-print,
  #section-to-print * {
      visibility: visible;
  }
  #section-to-print {
      position:absolute;
      top: -15px;
      left: 0;
      font-size:smaller;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the javascript tag, as this is clearly a question about css.

Answer (score 0):

Always insert a page break after each  element (when printing):

```
@media print {
    element {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

The page-break-after property sets whether a page break should occur AFTER a specified element.

Comment: What element would work best to connect this to, I am only printing a single div and then there is a table inside that.